# Twolined ovalbox in Beamer class

Tags: beamer

I would like to have a twolined Text which has a ovalbox around itself.
I do it with

```
{\huge \Ovalbox{\textcolor{darkred}{Two lined \\ text}}}
```

LaTex is ignoring the `\\` sign, how can it be accomplished?

Answer (score 1):

Use of `tikz` is one possible solution.  An ellipse shape is defined as `ell` style.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz,xcolor}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\tikzset{% 
ell/.style={draw,ellipse,minimum height=3em,text width=10em,line width=2pt, align=center},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[ell] {\textcolor{red}{\huge Two lined \\ text}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

**Edit:** If need to move this ovalbox around, for example,

[image]

Use `[remember picture,overlay] with shift={(x,y)}` skill, shown below

```
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item abc
\item This is a tikz node
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[ell,shift={(4cm,0cm)}] {\textcolor{red}{\huge Two lined \\ text}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\item def
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

Answer (score 0):

The hardest part of answering your question is working out which package defines `\Ovalbox`...it really would help us to help you if you posted a full MWE...it turns out that `\Ovalbox` is defined by [fancybox](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancybox).

The easiest way to do what you want is probably to put your tet into a `\parbox`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{fancybox}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{A fame}
  {\huge \Ovalbox{\parbox{40mm}{\centering\textcolor{red}{Two lined \\ text}}}}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Using this I obtain:

[image]

I added the `\centering` to the `\parbox` as I would certainly would want the text centered inside the oval.

As your question mentions `beamer` I have put everything inside a frame...

Answer (score 0):

You also can do that with the `stackengine` package, and either `fancybox`, or `pstricks` if you want more sophisticated boxes. Here are three samples:

```
\documentclass[svgnames, pdf]{report}

\usepackage{fancybox}

\usepackage{beamerarticle}
\usepackage{stackengine}

\usepackage{pst-node}
\setstackEOL{\\}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l@{\qquad}l}
With \texttt{fancybox}:&
\Ovalbox{\color{DarkRed}\huge\Centerstack{Two lined \\ text}}
\bigskip\\
With \texttt{pstricks}: \\
& \psset{linecolor = Coral!75, linewidth = 1.2pt, linearc=.4, cornersize = absolute}
\psframebox[framesep = 1pt]{\psframebox[linewidth=0.6pt, linearc = .325]{\color{DarkRed}\huge\Centerstack{Two lined \\ text}}}
\bigskip \\
& \psovalbox[linecolor = Coral!75, linewidth=0.8pt, doubleline = true]{\color{DarkRed}\huge\Centerstack{Two lined \\ text}}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is this possible to change the rule color for `\ovalbox`?

Comment: @MadyYuvi: Quite easily: in the optional arguments of `\psovalbox`, change the value of linecolor to whatever  colour you please

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, I meant that `\usepackage{fancybod}` and `\ovalbox`, not for `\psovalbox`, sorry for not asking clearly...

Comment: @MadyYuvi: I've found back this old .tex file on my system. Just use `\begingroup\color{some colour}Ovalbox{\color{text colour}…} \end{group}`.

Comment: Thanks for your quick suggestion, sorry just now I switch off my PC and went to Bed, will confirm you tomorrow...But much thanks for your quick suggestion....

Comment: We do not have the same time zone, it seems… :-)

Comment: It's working like a champ...you really great and much thanks for your timely help....Shall I make this as separate question? Please advise...

Comment: @MadyYuvi: I don't think it's necessary. Have a good day!